# How to extract data from query and then group by the extracted data

Tags: oracle

I have a Oracle table from which I have to extract all rows that have a certain date pattern that is appended at the end of the data. No problem there.

What I am stuck with is, how do I recursively or in another way be able to get the results for the next 30 days and display the count per each date range.

Sample data in that the table is:

```
Client (Column)
blah1_Client1_blah1_RECLAIM20160725
blah2_Client2_blah2_RECLAIM20160726
blah3_Client3_blah3_RECLAIM20160727
blah4_Client4_blah4_RECLAIM20160728
...
...
...
blahN_ClientN_blahN_RECLAIM20160731

DataCenter (Column)
Datacenter1
Datacenter2
Datacenter3
Datacenter4
..
..
..
DatacenterN
```

I'm expecting to be able to have my query give me the results of the Clients for next 30 days based on the date extracted in Client Column along with what Datacenter it belongs to and the count of how many Clients per DataCenter

So it should be something like this. The preceding text of the Client column are too unique and hence I want to extract the below patter and then list them.

```
DataCenter    Client            Count
Datacenter1   RECLAIM20160728   10
Datacenter2   RECLAIM20160727   7
Datacenter3   RECLAIM20160725   15
Datacenter4   RECLAIM20160726   23
```

My query today is as follows:

```
SELECT Datacenter, Client
FROM Table
WHERE volume LIKE '%RECLAIM201607%' and ROWNUM < 5;
```

or

```
SELECT Datacenter, COUNT (Datacenter)
FROM Table
WHERE volume LIKE '%RECLAIM201607%'
GROUP BY DataCenter;
```

Query 2 is is more likely the one that aligns close to my requirement but it does not list the dates and hence I do not know how many Reclaims are going to be done per Datacenter per day.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

two versions: one based on sysdate, works starting from the date of run, the second based on a literal filter date...

```
SELECT 
       DATACENTER, 
       SUBSTR(CLIENT, INSTR(CLIENT,'_RECLAIM20')) AS CLIENT,
       COUNT(CLIENT)
FROM TABLE_CLIENTS
WHERE TO_DATE(SUBSTR(SUBSTR(CLIENT, INSTR(CLIENT,'_RECLAIM20')), 9), 'YYYYMMDD') > SYSDATE
  AND TO_DATE(SUBSTR(SUBSTR(CLIENT, INSTR(CLIENT,'_RECLAIM20')), 9), 'YYYYMMDD') <= SYSDATE + 30 
-- WHERE TO_DATE(SUBSTR(SUBSTR(CLIENT, INSTR(CLIENT,'_RECLAIM20')), 9)) > DATE('20160701')
-- AND TO_DATE(SUBSTR(SUBSTR(CLIENT, INSTR(CLIENT,'_RECLAIM20')), 9)) <= DATE('20160701') + 30
GROUP BY 
DATACENTER, 
SUBSTR(CLIENT, INSTR(CLIENT,'_RECLAIM20'))
```